# Yii beginTransaction sets chained mode on Sybase

Tags: php, stored-procedures, transactions, yii, sap-ase

I have run into an issue with stored procedures and multi-statement transactions using Yii connecting to sybase via odbc.

To isolate the following error I was experiencing when running a stored procedure inside a transaction...

```
CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[ZZZZZ]: <>: 7713 [Sybase][ODBC Driver][Adaptive Server Enterprise]Stored procedure 'myStoredProcedure' may be run only in unchained transaction mode. The 'SET CHAINED OFF' command will cause the current session to use unchained transaction mode. (SQLExecute[7713] at /builddir/build/BUILD/php-5.3.3/ext/pdo_odbc/odbc_stmt.c:254). The SQL statement executed was: exec myStoredProcedure
```

I attempted the following very simple test:

```
$connection=Yii::app()->db;
$transaction = Yii::app()->db->beginTransaction();
$sql="select 'Tranchained'=@@tranchained";  //0=off, 1=on
$command=$connection->createCommand($sql);
error_log('Chained Mode On or Off ='.$command->queryScalar());
$transaction->commit();
```

The error log shows Chained Mode On or Off = 1, which means the transaction is turning chained mode on.  This is the opposite of what I thought it was supposed to do.  I also confirmed that the chained mode is off outside of this transaction, so I am sure it is the transaction that is turning it on.

The simple solution is to add a sql statement to turn off chained mode inside the transaction by inserting the following code inside the transaction (at the top):

```
$sql='set chained off';
$command=$connection->createCommand($sql);
$command->execute();
```

And this works for my simple example.  However it does not work when I use it my actual application, because I am using a multi-statement transaction, so I get the following error:

```
CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[ZZZZZ]: <>: 226 [Sybase][ODBC Driver][Adaptive Server Enterprise]SET CHAINED command not allowed within multi-statement transaction. (SQLExecute[226] at /builddir/build/BUILD/php-5.3.3/ext/pdo_odbc/odbc_stmt.c:254). The SQL statement executed was: set chained off
```

I have also tried:

```
$connection->setAutoCommit(false);
```

to no avail

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution.  Don't use

```
Yii::app()->db->beginTransaction();
```

Rather do this, which actually works and behaves as expected

```
$sql='begin transaction'; //or commit transaction, or rollback transaction
$command=$connection->createCommand($sql);
$command->execute();
```

A make-shift class could be created as follows (probably a more elegant way to do this).

```
class SybaseDb {

    public function beginTransaction() {
        $connection=Yii::app()->db;
        $sql='
            begin transaction 
        ';
        $command=$connection->createCommand($sql);
        $command->execute();        
    }

    public function rollBack() {
        $connection=Yii::app()->db;     
        $sql='
            rollback transaction 
        ';
        $command=$connection->createCommand($sql);
        $command->execute();            
    }

    public function commit() {
        $connection=Yii::app()->db; 
        $sql='
            commit transaction 
        ';
        $command=$connection->createCommand($sql);
        $command->execute();        
    }   

}
```